# Download Google map marker icon from url using Picasso

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, picasso

I'm trying to load Google map marker icons from the web using Picasso library. I've found this way to produce it in fragment class...

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(26.890768, 75.753915);
        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load("image-url.png")
                    .resize(60, 60)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(new TMarker(latLng, objects.get(0)));
    }
});
```

**TMarker.class** is implementation of **com.squareup.picasso.Target** as following...

```
class TMarker implements Target {
    LatLng latLng;
    Marker marker;

    TMarker(LatLng latLng, JsonObject object) {
        this.latLng = latLng;
        this.marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_marker_default)));
        this.marker.setTag(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

I think it's the easiest approach to do this. Now the problem is, Downloaded marker image is not being displayed first time when map (fragment) is loaded. As we reload the fragment, I mean come again on this map fragment, image has been displayed every time. So it's the problem of the very first time ;)

Please provide guidelines what I've missed!